# ApplicationProperties are empty for a received message(ServiceBusReceivedMessage) from the dead-lettered queue in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, queue, message, azureservicebus

#### Library name and version

Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.10.0

#### Describe the bug

We have tried to modify the metadata for a message dead-letter in two different ways :

1. Modifying the custom properties using the method below.
   DeadLetterMessageAsync(
   ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
   IDictionary<string, object> propertiesToModify = default,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
   We have create a custom dictionary with the properties to be modified in the dictionary and passed it to the param above.
   Checking in the azure portal, for the dead-letter message we can see custom properties (Key, Value) getting reflected.

However while trying to receive the message from the Dead-letter queue as ServiceBusReceivedMessage
and checked the applicationProperties field. The dictionary (ApplicationProperties) doesn't have any key value pairs at all.

2. We have also tried another method
   DeadLetterMessageAsync(
   ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
   string deadLetterReason,
   string deadLetterErrorDescription = default,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
   We have modified the ErrorDescription with some message and dead-lettered it. Post that while receiving the message, it doesn't have the deadLetterErrorDescription at all. From the library source code, it looks like the field deadLetterErrorDescription is getting extracted from the ApplicationProperties, which is again empty.

#### Expected behavior

In both the scenarios #1 and #2, we are expecting the applicationProperties in the received message to be hydrated with the custom properties as showing up in the portal.

#### Actual behavior

ApplicationProperties field in the ServiceBusReceivedMessage is empty.

#### Reproduction Steps

Send a message with error description to the dead-lettered queue and try to receive the message from the dead-lettered queue. Try to read if there are any keys from the applicationProperties.

Also raised this in the github space: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/35443

Edit :
This is a false callout. There is no bug in any of the versions.

Comment: Worth pointing out you’ve raised this with the Azure SDKs for .NET repo, https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/35443.

Comment: You should use the latest version of the SDK to eliminate any chances of a bug being fixed. For ASB, it would be version [7.13.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) as of today. Dead-lettering with a reason using a dictionary or simpler form works as expected. When posting something that's not working for you, it helps to have a repro link to the code you have confirmed as not working.

Comment: @SeanFeldman From the service bus explorer, we have checked if the custom properties for this message in the dead-letter queue is reflecting as expected or not. They are perfectly reflecting, but not while trying to receive a message via the code.

Comment: I don't know what and how you are testing. W/o seeing the code, I can't really say anything other than I've tried to reproduce the issue and couldn't. Dead-lettered messages with a reason contained the properties set upon dead-lettering. Show your code.

Comment: @SeanFeldman On debugging the code, we have found that the processor is listening to a completely different dead-lettered queue, which is resulting in this. This is a false callout. Thanks a lot for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

> When a message is dead-lettered, the message is moved to the dead-letter queue along with the reason for dead-lettering and the error description. The `dead-letter reason` and `error description` are added to the message properties.

Thanks @`Sean Feldman` for the comments.

You need to install the NuGet `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus -Version 7.13.1`

[image]

I tried the below approach and able to read the properties.

Inserted messages to the Service bus queue and read the messages and made them move to Dead letter queue using the below code.

[image]

Sample code to read messages.

```
string connSB = "Connection";
string que = "myqueue11";
string Remove_msg = "Hello";  
QueueClient Qclnt = new QueueClient(connSB, que);
MessageReceiver msgRcvr = new MessageReceiver(connSB, que, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
        while (true)
        {
            Message message = await msgRcvr.ReceiveAsync();
            if (message == null || message.Body == null || message.Body.Length == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            string messageContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
            if ((messageContent.Contains(Remove_msg)))
            {
                await msgRcvr.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
                Console.WriteLine($"Item '{Remove_msg}' not found.");
            }
        }

        await Qclnt.CloseAsync();
        await msgRcvr.CloseAsync();
```

Code in C# to read the properties.

```
string connSB = @"Conn String";
string queue = "myqueue11";
ServiceBusClient clnt = new ServiceBusClient(connSB);
ServiceBusReceiver receiver = clnt.CreateReceiver(queue, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
            {
                    SubQueue = SubQueue.DeadLetter
            });
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage msg = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();
            if (msg == null)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("No messages available in the dead-letter queue.");
            }

     else
        {
            if (msg.ApplicationProperties.Count > 0)
              {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> prop in msg.ApplicationProperties)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine($"Key: {prop.Key}, Value: {prop.Value}");
                  }
                }
             else
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("No ApplicationProperties found for the message.");
               }
                await receiver.CloseAsync();
                await clnt.DisposeAsync();
          }
```

Dead letter queue Properties.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a bug in the older version that is causing the issue ?

Comment: Yes, as per the GitHub it is a [BUG.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/35443)

Comment: No, that is raised as an issue by me in the azure sdk space

Comment: The`ApplicationProperties` property of the `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` class is a dictionary of application-specific message properties. If the `ApplicationProperties` are empty for a received message from the dead-lettered queue, it could be because the message was not properly formatted, or the message was not sent with any application-specific properties.

Comment: And the difference between Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.10.0 and 7.13.1, it is possible that there were changes made to the library that affected the way `ApplicationProperties` are handled. I would recommend checking the release notes for both versions [ServiceBus_7.13.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus_7.13.1/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/CHANGELOG.md) and [ServiceBus_7.10.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus_7.10.0/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: On debugging the code, we have found that the processor is listening to a completely different dead-lettered queue, which is resulting in this. This is a false callout. Thanks a lot for your help.